# Android app bad performance and rendering

Tags: android, performance, rendering

I have problem with android app. I developed this app by tutorial in android studio. That app works fine, but there is problem with Android 4.4 .

On my phone with Android 6.0 it works good
[My phone image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjlkG.png)

But on my friend phone with Android 4.4 it doesn't work.
[Friend phone image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMT48.jpg)

Please, can you help me? I don't know how repair that. I tried google, but I don't found my problem. Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.expertik.msg">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score -2):

A manifest error or string error is usually caused by a manifest error when you do something wrong.

Comment: Here this should fix it go here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: I do not think it is because manifest.I made the application in xamarin and the problem was same. And now in the android studio there's the problem again.